# Need to add space at the end of each line using Unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix, addition, space, using

I need to add space at the end of each line except the header lines.Below is the example of my file:

```
13120000005000002100000000000000000000081D000
231200000000000    000     00XY018710V000000000                        
231200000000000    000     00XY018710V000000000
13120000012000007000000000000000000000081D000
231200000000000   000     00XY057119V000000000
```

So 1st & 4th line(starting with 131200 ) is my header line...Except my header I want 7-8spaces at the end of each line.

Please find the code that I am currently using:

```sh
find_list=`find *.dat -type f`
Filename='*.dat'
filename='xyz'
for file in $find_list

do
 sed -i -e 's/\r$/         /' "$file"
  n=1
   loopcounterpre=""

newfile=$(echo "$filename" | sed -e 's/\.[^.]*$//')".dat"

while read line
do
        if [[ $line != *[[:space:]]* ]]

        then
                rowdetail=$line

                loopcounter=$( echo "$rowdetail" | cut -b 1-6) 
        if [[ "$loopcounterpre" == "$loopcounter" ]]
        then 
         loopcounterpre=$loopcounter
         #Increases the counter for  in the order of 001,002 and so on until the Pay entity is changed
         n=$((n+1))
        #Resets the Counter to 1 when the pay entity changes
        else
         loopcounterpre=$loopcounter
         n=1
        fi
        printf -v m "%03d" $n
        llen=$(echo ${#rowdetail})

        rowdetailT=$(echo "$rowdetail" | cut -b 1-$((llen-3)))
                ip=$rowdetailT$m
                echo "$ip" >> $newfile

        else
                rowdetail=$line
        echo "$rowdetail" >> $newfile
        fi

done < $file

bye
EOF

done
```

Comment: So, is it 1st & 4th lines or lines starting with 131200 you don't want more space after? And is it 7 or 8 spaces or just a random of those 2?

Comment: lines starting with 131200 & 1351000 will be header files...Under these lines there will be multiple lines...We want spaces added in those lines

Comment: I could get the spaces added at the end of each line except the header but the output file is now trimming the first two lines of the file and rest of the file is generated properly...Could you please help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

The entire script can be replaced with one line of *GNU* `sed`:

```
sed -is '/^131200\|^1351000/!s/$/       /' $(find *.dat -type f)
```

Comment: No headers will be there in file at multiple lines...we already performing some actions for header lines and that is perfectly working fine

Comment: @naeemaparween, See revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
$ awk '{print $0 ($0~/^(131200|1351000)/?"":"        ")}' file
```

`print` current record `$0` and if it starts with `$0~/^(131200|1351000)/` print `""` else `:` print `"        "`.